# Conectar PC a dominio Active Directory

Tags: windows10, powershell, dominio

Estoy intentando unir a un dominio mi ordenador mediante powershell y este me da el siguiente error:

> El equipo 'PC17142' no pudo unirse al dominio 'virtualbox.local' desde su grupo de trabajo actual 'WORKGROUP' con el siguiente mensaje de error: Acceso denegado.

El comando que ejecuto, es el siguiente:

```
add-computer -computername "PC17142" -domainName virtualbox.local -cred Administrador -Verbose
```

PD: El powershell se ejecuta como administrador, así omitiendo la posibilidad de que sea falta de permisos.

Sabrian ustedes decirme como solucionar esto? La intención es unir este ordenador a un dominio mediante un comando PowerShell.

Comment: pregunto, el usuario administrador que estas usando es el administrador local del equipo, o es administrador de dominio? porque son diferentes. Si usas uno de local es muy posible que no tenga permisos (por eso lo de acceso denegado).

Comment: El usuario que uso (en este caso Administrador), tiene acceso a unir gente al dominio (porque mediante interficie grafica, puedo unir a gente de forma exitosa), este usuario es el del dominio.
¿Que me falla entonces?

Comment: Alguien sabe solucionar este problema?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Es el único error que te aparece? Si revisas la documentación del comando Add-Computer existen más ejemplos sobre el uso de credenciales para poder contactar al dominio.